# Safari and IE ajax issues with subsequent calls (.then)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I've got this code:

```
var request1 = this.add(prod_id, pack_id_combination, button, pack_qty).then(function(rdata1){
  // this always works
  this.add(prod_id, case_id_combination, button, case_qty).then(function(rdata2){    
    // this sometimes (random) doesn't work
  }.bind(this), function(req, status, error){ console.log('case error',req, status, error); });
}.bind(this), function(){ console.log('pack error'); });
```

I omitted the rest of the code because it's a huge class and it's also  impossible to build a jsfiddle, too much things.

But here's the facts:

- my js points to a php file returning data. It does ajax calls via the `add()` function (see below)
- it always works for the first call, it sometimes doesn't work for the second call.
- on the log, status = 'error', error = '' (empty, so no info here)
- I also know for sure that the second add(), if called alone with the same params, will always work.
- Furthermore, it has these problems ONLY in safari and IE, not in chrome, ff, android
- Furthermore, it has these problems ONLY if tested online, while in my local environment always works properly.
- Safari says it looses the connection. This is the only information I can get

the `add()` function is quite trivial:

```
add:function(idProduct, idCombination, callerElement, quantity){
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST'
        ,headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
        ,url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime()
        ,cache: false
        ,dataType : "json"
        ,data: 'controller=cart&add=1&ajax=true&qty=' + ((quantity && quantity != null) ? quantity : '1') + '&id_product=' + idProduct + '&token=' + static_token + ( (parseInt(idCombination) && idCombination != null) ? '&ipa=' + parseInt(idCombination): '')
        ,success:function(data, status, req){
            console.log('ok');
        }
        ,error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
},//end add()
```

So, my question: is there a way to avoid this problem? Is it a common pitfall? Are there common practices to avoid this kind of issues?

Comment: As written, it's definitely not going to work. In the expression `this.a.then(function() { this.b()})`, the second `this` object will be the global scope, which is almost certainly not what you want.  In `this.a.then(() => { this.b()})`, both thises point to the same object.

Comment: Mmm are you sure? I'm binding everything. Also, as written, in fact it doesn't work only on remote environment and only in safari and IE.

Comment: pretty sure.  It's the major difference between fat-arrow and this.

Comment: I'm using jquery, and no js6. Could you please post some more explicit code on a regular answer so I can better understand?

Also, how about all my bind(this) and the fact that it works (it's a production site online since some years now) in the listed use cases?

Comment: Whether or not this is correctly set, I don't see how request1 can make sense without a return statement on the internal this.add

Comment: In promises, the onresolved/onrejected callbacks in `.then` only get a single argument - but you expect three in one of your onrejected - i.e. `function(req, status, error)`

Comment: Guys, thank you, but I really think you're both not reading carefully my question and my code, and also are assuming pure javascript ES5/6, while it's not, it's jquery, just see the question tags.
Jaromanda X, please see the then() jquery docs.
Danh, please carefully read the add() function.

Also, you all, please carefully read the listed use cases. It all works on specific browsers and/or envoronments, so we are not speaking of syntax errors here. There must be something more sublte. I need someone who really knows specific jquery ajax issues.

Comment: Downvotes should be commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my issue was solved by using a **GET request instead of a POST** one.

Probably both Safari and IE are not able to correctly manage 2 subsequent ajax POST requests, at least in specific circumstances. Or, the jquery 2.1.3 (version used here) implementation has some kind of subtle  problems/bugs.

But since I often have random css/js issues with both IE (surprise...) and Safari (yes...), I guess it's them and not jquery.